# Syntax error in INSERT into statement vb c#

Tags: c#

I am a newbie and currently having problems with this part of my code where i get a syntax error after clicking the button to be recorded in the database.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         FlightConn.Open();
        oleDbCmd.Connection = FlightConn;

        oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_flight (fld_PassengerName, fld_destination, fld_class, fld_date, fld_time) ('" +
        this.textBox1.Text + "', '" + this.textBox2.Text + "', '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "');";
        int temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (temp > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = null;
            textBox2.Text = null;
            comboBox1.Text = null;
            comboBox2.Text = null;
            dateTimePicker1.Text = null; 


            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Failed to Add");
        }
       FlightConn.Close();
    }
```

any ideas what the problem is? thank you for any future answers

Comment: is it c# or vb.net? why have you tagged both? where does the syntax error occur? have you stepped through your code to see what the values are at each point?

Comment: are you missing VALUES between the fields ) and values (  ?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `VALUES` keyword in that `INSERT` statement?

Comment: You should also add SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection. Also, do you validate any of the input values before saving them.

Comment: Aside from anything else, this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks. Use parameterized SQL - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You insert query is missing the Values keyword. `Insert into tablename(field1,field2) values(value1,value2)`

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL command is missing a clause. You should also use parameterized queries rather than inputting the values in plain text into your query. It makes the query more secure since you won't have to worry so much about SQL injection.

Change this:

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_flight (fld_PassengerName, fld_destination, fld_class, fld_date, fld_time) ('" +
    this.textBox1.Text + "', '" + this.textBox2.Text + "', '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "');";
```

To something more like this:

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_flight(fld_PassengerName, fld_destination, fld_class, fld_date, fld_time) values(@PassengerName, @Destination, @Class, @Date, @Time)";

List<OleDbParameter> args = new List<OleDbParameter>();
args.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PassengerName", textBox1.Text));
args.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Destination", textBox2.Text));
args.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Class", comboBox1.SelectedItem));
args.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Date", comboBox2.SelectedItem));
args.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Time", dateTimePicker1.Value));

oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add(args.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to specify "values" keyword.. try this

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_flight (fld_PassengerName, fld_destination, fld_class, fld_date, fld_time) values('" +
    this.textBox1.Text + "', '" + this.textBox2.Text + "', '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "');";
```

Comment: No thanks in the answers please and the keyword is "`VALUES`" ;)

Comment: I'd also suggest that any answer which propagates a SQL Injection vulnerability is not helping nearly as much as it could.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the **"VALUES"** keyword in your sql statement

Answer (score 0):

Your sql string must be;

```
string.Format(@"INSERT INTO tbl_flight (fld_PassengerName, fld_destination, fld_class, fld_date, fld_time) 
                                        VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}');",
                              this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text, this.comboBox1.SelectedItem,
                              this.comboBox2.SelectedItem, this.dateTimePicker1.Value);
```